# How to create a right arrow on top layout using xml shapes in android?

Tags: android, xml, drawable

[image]

How to create a right arrow on top layout using xml shapes in android like this??

Comment: It's probably a nine patch, not an XML drawable

Comment: I don't think it's posible with XML. Use 9-patch drawable instead